# linux + cant run dialog utility + got errors

Tags: software-installation, suse

Problem is as follows:

Linux kernel: 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP

I’ve installed “dialog” utility ( `/usr/bin/dialog` ), just copied bin file to `/usr/bin`

When I have tried to run it, error message regarding missing `libncursesw.so.5` lib appeared.

To solve the problem I try to copied the file `libncursesw.so.5`  to `/usr/lib/` 
but not help

Now, I got another error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.5: file too short
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1):

You don't "install" applications like this on Linux (apart from some corner cases). Use your distribution package manager to install what you need - it will automatically pull in all th required packages. In case of SUSE Linux derived distributions (since you are using the `/suse` tag) use

```
zypper in dialog
```

(`in` is short for `install`) or

```
yast -i
```

which should give you interactive dialogues. You obviously have to run these with root privileges to be able to modify the root filesystem. If you already have the *distribution* RPMs at hand, you can use `rpm -Uvh package1.rpm package2.rpm ...`

The main reasons why just copying stuff into your file system is wrong:

- source of the binaries may not be reliable, especially from security point of view. you just don't run any programs somebody gives you - using distribution package gives you at least some assurance about the content of the package (for example by being cryptographically signed);
- the binaries are linked against shared libraries (e.g. libncursesw in your case) - if you don't provide compatible-enough library, you are bound for problems (which are hard to debug).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where you got the `libncursesw.so.5` file from. It seems that it's not a real library.

In any case, when you have missing libraries, you should install them from your package manager:

```
# yum install libncursesw5
```

Comment: in case of Debian based `sudo apt-get install libncursesw5` ;)

Comment: SUSE doesn't do `yum` (RedHat does) :)